# Get the locations of selected user

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query,

```
$query=mysql_query("select * 
                    from quiz_grades as grade,
                         user_info_data as info,
                         user as user 
                    where user.id=grade.userid 
                      and user.id=info.userid 
                      and grade.quiz=12 
                      and info.fieldid=1 
                      and info.data='AP'
                    order by data ASC, grade DESC");
```

From the following table,

`$USER->id` is current logged in user variable.

if `userid`=`$USER->id` belongings to AP, all AP should be display.
If `userid`=`$USER->id` belongings to TL, all TL should be display.

`info.data` storing AP and TL records.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>userid</th>
    <th>data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AP</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>TL</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AP</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AP</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>TL</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>TL</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>AP</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>TL</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>TL</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>TL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What field in what table indicates the state (e.g. Andhra, etc.)  for the users?

Comment: `user_info_data` table, `data` field

Comment: In 1992, SQL updated its standard. Perhaps it's time to take advantage of that fact.

Comment: Do you have a question, or stating how you feel MySQL should work?

Comment: Having `user_info_data` table with `userid` and `data` columns.
`userid` having 10 records(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `data` having 10 records(AP, TL, AP, AP, AP, TL TL, TL, AP, AP).
`userid`=3 from AP.
Want to display all AP records if i select `userid`=3
Want to display all TL records if i select `userid`=2

Comment: So you have 3 tables: user, user_info_data and quiz_grade. You want information from quiz_grade based on the user's id. Correct so far? How does the quiz_grade table look like, what are its columns?

Comment: Hi Niddro, I want information from `user_info_data` table.
Check the table of code snippet in the above.

Comment: If `userid`=3 from AP, All AP only to be display. and $USER->id is current logged in user. have to use `userid`=$USER->id in MySQL quesry

Comment: Does anybody know the logic please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include that condition as well in your query like below, considering that you have a location field in your `user` table

```
select grade.* from quiz_grades as grade
join user as user on user.id=grade.userid and grade.quiz=12
join user_info_data as info on user.id=info.userid  
where `fieldid`=1 
and info.data = 'telengana'
order by data ASC, grade DESC
```

Comment: It is displaying single record with grade and Rank.
Nut, i want all the records.

Comment: $query=mysql_query("select * from quiz_grades as grade,user_info_data as info,user as user where user.id=grade.userid and user.id=info.userid and grade.quiz=12 and `fieldid`=1 order by data ASC, grade DESC");
$data = '';
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$rec['username'];
$rec['grade'];
$rec['data'];
if($rec['data']!=$data)
{
$data = $rec['data'];
$i=1;
}
else
{
$i++;
}
echo $rec['username'];
echo $rec['grade'];
echo $rec['data'];
echo $i;
}

Comment: @Raja, try the edited query in answer and see if it works.

Comment: Having `user_info_data` table with `userid` and `data` columns.
`userid` having 10 records(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `data` having 10 records(AP, TL, AP, AP, AP, TL TL, TL, AP, AP).
`userid`=3 from AP.
Want to display all AP records if i select `userid`=3
Want to display all TL records if i select `userid`=2

Comment: Does anybody know the logic please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a location field to use (`locationField`):

```
$query=mysql_query("
  SELECT * 
  FROM   quiz_grades AS grade, 
       user_info_data AS info, 
       USER AS USER 
  WHERE  USER.id = grade.userid 
       AND USER.id = info.userid 
       AND grade.quiz = 12 
       AND ` fieldid `= 1
       AND `location` IN (SELECT location FROM user_info_data  WHERE user_info_data.userid = {$USER->id})
  ORDER  BY data ASC, 
          grade DESC ");
```

Comment: location stored in `user_info_data` table with `data` column

Comment: Having `user_info_data` table with `userid` and `data` columns.
`userid` having 10 records(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `data` having 10 records(AP, TL, AP, AP, AP, TL TL, TL, AP, AP).
`userid`=3 from AP.
Want to display all AP records if i select `userid`=3
Want to display all TL records if i select `userid`=2

Comment: Does anybody know the logic please